# Chromebook does not show app page

Tags: chromebook

A friend has two google accounts and one chromebook. Neither google account will display the app page on the chromebook. Prolly not helpful, but included is a screen capture of the message.

[screen capture showing the app page error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEgB.png)

Logging into any other computer properly displays the app page. Logging out and in on the chromebook doesn't change things. Clearing cache on the chromebook doesn't help. No joy.

I've asked him to check his proxy settings, and to have a friend try yet a different google account.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck posting this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you--so many places to post, so little time to know what the most appropriate places are. (-;